# comparison operators in ms sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

SELECT NULLIF(1 > 0, 1);

In MySQL that returns NULL. In SQL Server it gives me a syntax error because of the <. eg.

SELECT 1 > 0;

That, too, works fine in MySQL, but not in SQL Server. Any ideas as to what I can do to work around this?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using case ?

Comment: In SQL Server, `NULLIF` expects a *scalar* expression, not a *boolean* expression. In SQL Server 2012, `IIF` does accept boolean expressions (and only boolean expressions), so you can rewrite that as `SELECT IIF(1 > 0, NULL, 1);` - I think. I'm not sure what result you're actually expecting (e.g. what does MySQL return if you replace the expression with 1 < 0? I can't keep track of its crazy rules and behavior).

Answer (score 3):

MySQL is more flexible than other databases in using calculations in queries.  You can use `CASE` statements in SQL Server to achieve the same results though:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15602)